# C++ Detect if there exists a function by name that accepts a particular type

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I would like to detect of there is an insertion operator for a given type. Ordinarily I would check that an overloaded function exists with the proper signature. Say I have a class A, then

```
template<typename T>
struct insert_operator_type
{
   using type = typename std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&, const T&);
};
...
std::is_same<
        decltype(static_cast<typename insert_operator_type<A>::type> (&operator<<)),
        std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&, A const&)
     >::value
```

will tell me they are the same and I can deduce that the operator exists. With operator<< however it's possible that a type B resolves into a type A. Say something like

```
template<typename T>
class A 
{
public:
    T* type1 = nullptr;
};

typedef A<int>  BImpl;

class B : public BImpl
{
public:

    B() {}
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A<T>& a)
{
    os << "printing A<T>" << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

Now I can

```
 B b;
 std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

But there's no

```
std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&, B const&)
```

instead the compiler figures out to use the BImpl version and the idiom fails to identify that there is an insertion operator for B.

Can I determine that an overloaded function exists such that the function may not be specified for a particular type but for some type the given type will convert into?

Comment: I don't see an insertion operator for `B`, I only see one for `A<T>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to just use SFINAE to check whether the whole expression doing the insertion is valid.

```
// std::void_t in C++1z
template <class...>
using void_t = void;

template <class, class = void_t<>>
struct can_be_ostreamed : std::false_type { };

template <class T>
struct can_be_ostreamed<T, void_t<
    decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>())
>> : std::true_type { };
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/436370e643012ca8)

Comment: Can you explain what std::declval<> is doing here?

Comment: @MichaelConlen `std::declval` is used to obtain an expression of arbitrary type, without having to actually construct an instance (which could be problematic due to a non-accessible constructor). It can only be used in non-evaluated contexts, like `decltype`.

Comment: So it looks like this does work though I had to discover that in gcc 4 it's broken and reports that can_be_ostreamed<std::vector<int>>::value is true.

Comment: It appears that second 2.3 of the proposal for void_t addresses the "bug" which is really a divergence of opinion on how to read the standard. 
 
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3911